# Plone - cannot copy and paste view in Zope Management Interface's plone_skins' plone_content

Tags: plone, zope, zope.interface

We are using Plone 4.1.2, and are having problem doing a copy and paste of a view in Zope Management Interface's plone_skins' plone_content.   We get this error message:

Thank you very much in anticipation.

```
You are here: Home › portal_skins › plone_content
We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…
Here is the full error message:

Display traceback as text

Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module OFS.CopySupport, line 206, in manage_pasteObjects
Module OFS.CopySupport, line 537, in _verifyObjectPaste
CopyError: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Not Supported</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"> <FORM ACTION="manage_main" METHOD="GET" > <TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="10"> <TR> <TD VALIGN="TOP"> <BR> <CENTER><B><FONT SIZE="+6" COLOR="#77003B">!</FONT></B></CENTER> </TD> <TD VALIGN="TOP"> <BR><BR> <CENTER> The object <em>folder_summary_view</em> does not support this operation. </CENTER> </TD> </TR> <TR> <TD VALIGN="TOP"> </TD> <TD VALIGN="TOP"> <CENTER> <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE=" Ok "> </CENTER> </TD> </TR> </TABLE> </FORM> </BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you posted is an archaic one from the deep depths of Zope, but it is clear in your case. You are trying to copy something into a place that doesn't support copying.

Most skin layer folders in the ZMI reflect a filesystem directory on your disk. They are not showing you ZODB persisted objects, so you cannot add or remove items there through the ZMI.

If you want to copy a skin item for customization, use the 'customize' button at the bottom of their view to create a persistent copy in the ZODB, usually in the special `custom` folder, which you can then alter. Or you can find the file on the filesystem and make a copy there (into your own skins layer folder, for example).

Comment: Thank you Martin Pieters, but if I do a "customize" on say the folder_summary_view, won't I lose the original folder_summary_view because my customized view will replace it?   So the question is how do I create my own folder view in ZMI?   Thank you once again.

Comment: Okay, I think I am beginning to get it.  The steps are:

Comment: In /portal_skins/plone_content, click on folder_summary_view
In /portal_skins/plone_content/folder_summary_view, click on Customize button
In /portal_skins/custom/folder_summary_view, click on Save Changes

Now, the 'customized' folder_summary_view can be found in /portal_skins/custom

In /portal_skins/custom, select folder_summary_view, and click Rename
Change the name to say fx_folder_summary_view

Comment: In /portal_skins/custom/fx_folder_summary_view, modify the view and click Save Changes

In /portal_skins/custom, select fx_folder_summary_view, and click Copy

Go to /portal_types/Folder
and fx_folder_summaryP_view to Available view methods

Answer (score 1):

You can paste only into non-filesystem folders i.e. custom and ones created through-the-web in ZMI.